# Disable PyCharm auto-complete when space is pressed

Tags: pycharm, html-editor

When edit html file in pycharm, it always auto-complete <></> even if i don’t need.

For example:
I want type

`Learning Log`

but as long as i type writespace, it will become

`<Learning></Learning>`

I searched in the internet but there’s no same issue yet. Is there anyone know how to disabled it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't used Pycharm, but all the other Jetbrains products have auto completion settings through the menu progression 'Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion'

Comment: @schulmaster I tried it，but there’s total settings. I need more detail settings. Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Welp, I have the same issue. Tab does nothing but space converts string to a HTML tag...

Answer (score 1):

I found the option!

Got to `Settings > Editor > General > Code completion`

You see the box `Show suggestions as you type`?

Right bellow you want to uncheck `Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys`

[image]

It was driving me crazy.

Comment: You don't know how much this was annoying me - thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in 2020.

I looked everywhere but did not find any setting related to this (maybe I missed something).

But I fixed it by Restoring Default Setting. I think it was due to some plugins I installed but could not figure out which one. So, I just Restored the default setting.

`File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...`

This will set your IDE to the vanilla IDE.